# ¿Cómo Filtrar en Typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

Estoy pasando un programita que hice en windows forms con c# a Angular con ASP.NET, y estoy tratando de filtrar por nombre. En c# mi método para filtrar era algo así:

```
expedientes.Where(x => x.FechaCreacion >= FechaDesde
                                             && x.FechaCreacion <= FechaHasta
                                             && x.NombreExpediente.Contains(nombreExpediente)).ToList();
```

El filtro por fecha aún no lo hago pero pensaría que es más sencillo que el del nombre. El filtro que tengo hecho en typescript es el siguiente:

```
this.expedientes.filter(expediente => expediente.NombreExpediente === this.busqueda);
```

Edit:

La función es la siguiente:

```
buscarExpediente(): ExpedientesDto[] {
  const length = this.busqueda.length;
  console.log(length);
  if (length > 0) {
    this.hayBusqueda = true;
    console.log(this.expedientes.filter(expediente =>
        expediente.NombreExpediente.indexOf(this.busqueda)));
    return this.expedientes.filter(expediente => 
        expediente.NombreExpediente.indexOf(this.busqueda));
  }
  return this.expedientes;
}
```

[image: contenido de expedientes]

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, ya que en principio lo tienes bien salvo que en el código de c# utilizas la función Contains, y en el de typescript utilizas la igualdad por lo que te dará resultados diferentes. Cual es tu duda en concreto?

Comment: Mi duda en concreto es que ese código de c#, me devuelve todos los datos que contienen la letra "E" por ejemplo, pero la que tengo de typescript no, como puedo hacer para que lo haga! Además de que conforme escribo en el input sobre escribe el nombre del arreglo con lo que yo estoy escribiendo. Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que me has comentado te valdría esto:

```
this.expedientes.filter(expediente =>{
              return expediente.NombreExpediente.indexOf(this.busqueda) >= 0;
});
```

Sobre lo otro que comentas tendrías que añadir la función para ver como lo tienes.
Espero que te sirva el código.

Comment: Fíjate que lo acabo de probar y no me funciona aún. Pues lo que muestra es lo mismo que antes, sólo los datos que son extactamente iguales! Añadí la función a la pregunta

Comment: puedes mostrar el contenido de this.expedientes, el valor de this.busqueda y el resultado que devuelve el filter para ver que puede ocurrir.

Comment: ahí añadí una captura con el contenido de expedientes. El valor de this.busqueda es el de una caja de texto que tengo en mi componente html básicamente es el código ([ngModel]) = "busqueda"

Comment: He editado la respuesta con esto te tendría que ir

Comment: Pues no, aún no. De hecho si escribo "E" en mi input, no me devuelve nada!

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando `indexOf` mal, ya que la condición del filtro sólo sería falsa cuando `indexOf` devolviese 0, que significa que **ha encontrado el valor** en la posición 0. Debes comprobar que devuelve un valor **mayor que -1**, pero también podrías usar [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes).

```js
let expedientes=[];

for(let i=0;i<3;i++) {
  expedientes.push({ 
    NombreExpediente : `Expediente ${String.fromCharCode(i+65)}`
  });
}

console.log(expedientes)

let busqueda='A';

let resultado=expedientes.filter(e => e.NombreExpediente.includes(busqueda));

console.log('Resultado con includes',resultado);

resultado=expedientes.filter(e => e.NombreExpediente.indexOf(busqueda) >= 0);

console.log('Resultado con indexOf',resultado);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, tenías toda la razón.